# Strange std::is_constructible

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Let's look at this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// somewhere in main
using V = std::vector<int&>;
```

Ok, vector of references doesn't have any sense, but template instantiation works only on 'outer' level — inner entities doesn't instantiated if they are not used. So, this code compiles.

But

```
bool value = std::is_constructible_v<V>;
```

doesn't compile! WHY? I except that `value` should be just a `false`.

More specifically, I don't understand why this code (I mean expression inside the `decltype`) in a typical implementation of `is_constructible` raise compiler error instead of SFINAE:

```
namespace std {
namespace detail {
template <class, class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_helper : false_type {};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_helper<void_t<decltype(T{declval<Args>()...})>, T, Args...> : true_type {};
} // namespace detail

template <class T, class... Args>
using is_constructible = detail::is_constructible_helper<void, T, Args...>;
} // namespace std
```

The error messages from gcc look like the following:

> ```
> In file included from [various standard includes]
> In instantiation of 'class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int&>':
> required from [chain of compiler-created classes]
> error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'
>     allocate(size_type __n, const void* = static_cast<const void*>(0))
>     ^~~~~~~~
> error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'
>     deallocate(_Tp* __p, size_type __t)
>     ^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

and several similar messages pointing to other parts of the standard library's header files. These are followed by an error saying that `push_back(const value_type& __x)` cannot be overloaded with `push_back(value_type&& __x)`.

Comment: What compiler do you use? What error do you see?  Please add minimal reproducing example.

Comment: @IgorR. gcc, clang, it doesn't matter — all of them say something about `int&*`; in other words, they instantiate default constructor `std::vector<int&>` and get compiler error instead of using SFINAE.

Comment: So, most likely the error happens not in the *immediate context* of the argument substitution. But one needs more details to make an exact diagnosis.

Comment: `std::vector<int&>` is undefined behaviour. Containers are objects that store other objects ([container.requirements.general]). References are not objects.

Comment: My question is not about containers. You can use `std::span<int, 2>` instead of `std::vector<int&>`

Comment: `std::vector<int&>` is undefined. C++ says nothing about a program which contains such construct. It could compile, it could blow up your computer and run away with your girlfriend. I cannot reproduce any of this with `std::span`. If you have code that behaves strangely with `std::span`, post it.

Comment: Anyway, SFINAE doesn't mean "skip this if it doesn't compile", it means "skip this if *substitution fails*". In particular, SFINAE cannot be used to weed out invalid function or class bodies. In this case, substitution succeeds, there's no reason for it to fail.

Comment: Ok, I completely understand it. So, is there any possibility in C++ to write a trait which rejects a code that doesn't compile?

Comment: No I don't think there is a way to do it.